# What elements (in the pure form) would harm a human, if eaten?

Tags: elements, toxicity

What pure elements, if we eat it in a relatively small dose (around a piece of sugar), can be harmful/lethal for an average human? Is, for example, eating pure carbon bad for the organism?

Comment: Related: [Are there any good examples of commonly ingested molecules that contain particular toxic individual elements?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/24229/7951)

Comment: I think you need to be more specific with the question. Lots of things will kill you or could cause harm. Eating a diamond heated to 3000 K is probably bad. If you eat a large mass of carbon-14, that's probably also bad.

Answer (score 2):

> Is, for example, eating pure carbon bad for the organism?

No, quite the contrary.

Activated charcoal (in the form of powder or tablets) was/is traditionally used to treat diarrea. It is listed on the [WHO Model List of Essential Medicines](http://www.who.int/medicines/publications/essentialmedicines/EML_2015_FINAL_amended_NOV2015.pdf) on page 4.

Answer (score 1):

Another fun data point: polonium-210 has $\mathrm{LD}_{50}$ of approximately $50\ \mathrm{ng}$ by ingestion or $10\ \mathrm{ng}$ by inhalation. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polonium#Acute_effects)

Obviously, the answer is **yes** for some elements.

Answer (score 0):

I hear its all about the dose, even water can kill you if you drink too much.
And cyanide wont kill you if its a small dose, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWNpO5vvhpk

Comment: OP is asking about small dose

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more elements that probably would cause no harm if you ate a sugar-lump sized piece: B, Mg, Al, Si, S, Ti, V, Cr, Mn, Fe, Co, Ni, Cu, Pd, Ag, Sn, Pt, Au, Bi. Probably there are many more. Don't know about the rare earth elements. Also, all the noble gas elements, plus hydrogen, are nontoxic.

Comment: Sugar-lump sized pieces of most metals would probably break your teeth or get stuck in your throat. Other than that, those you listed are harmless indeed.

Comment: Copper isn't entirely benign; there is some literature on human toxicity (and, of course, it kills plants: copper sulfate is sometimes used to keep roots out of sewer pipe).   Trace amounts are beneficial, though.

Comment: Mg may give you gas (reacts readily with gastric HCl) and too much may displace calcium in bones and teeth.

Answer (score 0):

5 grams elemental at STP assuming no physical trauma:

Immediate  serious harm: P and group 1 metals and Calcium.

Comment: It would be good to mention that you mean _white_ phosphorus. Other forms are relatively harmless.

Comment: Regarding different allotropes, He would be harmless, but I would avoid eating 3 grams of $\ce{He2}$.

Comment: Unstable particles are usually not counted as allotropes.