# Why is Cadmium so carcinogenic compared to other heavy metals?

Tags: biochemistry, transition-metals

[This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3453642/pdf/12291_2008_Article_BF02864853.pdf) free article as well as [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0041008X09000349?via%3Dihub) article do a good job highlighting the carcinogenic effects of Cadmium and the mechanisms by which they occur. However, my question is why is Cadmium so carcinogenic **compared to other heavy metals?** What chemical property of Cadmium makes it more prone to these carcinogenic actions than, say, Mercury or Lead or some other heavy metal?

To give a more concrete example, the recommended safe levels of Lead in water is 50 ppb, whereas for Cadmium, it is 5 ppb. Why is there such a stark difference in their health effects?

Comment: Which standards for lead levels are you citing? The FDA cites 5 ppb in drinking water ([Table 4](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/csem/csem.asp?csem=34&po=8))

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24229/are-there-any-good-examples-of-commonly-ingested-molecules-that-contain-particul

Comment: Because of its combination of charge and radius mostly, or generally its individual chemical properties. It can squeeze into a number of places where it shouldn´t.